# What is the most efficient way to count the number of observations that fit a logical criteria?

Tags: r

Using the `ggplot2::diamonds` dataset, I am trying to count the number of diamonds that cost less than a certain amount.  The only way I could figure it out was to create a new variable and subset the data and then count the remaining observations in the new vector.

Example:

```
newVector <- subset(diamonds, price<600)
nrow(newVector)
```

I was wondering what the best way to solve this would be?  Since my method felt clunky.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `sum`

```
data(diamonds)  # library(ggplot2)
sum(diamonds$price < 600)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative using `table`:

```
table(diamonds$price < 600)
```

Output:

```
FALSE  TRUE 
49831  4109
```

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)    
diamonds %>%
      summarise(sum(price < 600))
```

Using `sqldf`:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("SELECT COUNT(price) 
      FROM diamonds
      WHERE price < 600")
```